# Different version of the Hilbert basis theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

How to prove the following version of the Hilbert basis theorem:

> $R$ is Noetherian if and only if $R[|x|]$ is Noetherian.

Of course, in view of the isomorphism:
$$\frac{R[|x|]}{(x)~R[|x|]} \simeq R$$
one direction follows. I'm struggling to come up with a proof for the converse. Any help is much appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the usual Hilbert basis theorem to show that $R[x]$ is Noetherian, and then note that $R[[x]]$ is the $(x)$-adic completion of the Noetherian ring $R[x]$ and hence Noetherian.

I think you can also directly adapt the usual argument about killing leading terms of polynomials.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The latter is the one I'm looking for. I still don't know how to prove that.